# Pagination for multiple repository calls in a single API, JAVA JPA

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, pagination

While doing pagination, in single api there are 2 repository calls

```
Sort sort = Sort.by("createdAt"). descending ();
Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize, sort);

list = walletdrawalRepo.findByUserOrderByCreatedAtDesc(user, paging); // 1

withdrwalRqlist = userRequestRepo.findByUserOrderByCreatedAtDesc(user, paging); // 2
```

and it is resulting in the double of actual pageSize because of the 2 repo calls.

Please help me how to solve this one.

Comment: Can you share the classes ?

Comment: Which classes do i need to share?